# Openfire does not respond to Smack login()

Tags: java, xmpp, openfire, smack

I am using Smack API trying to connect and login to the Openfire XMPP server which is setup on my laptop (localhost).

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration conf = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
            .setServiceName("win10-xps15")
            .setHost("192.168.1.100")
            .setPort(5222)
            .setCompressionEnabled(false)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .build();

    XMPPTCPConnection connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(conf);

    connection.connect();
    connection.login("admin", "password");
```

The connect() method is successful but the login() method fails with a NoResponse (timeout) exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:106)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException.newWith(SmackException.java:85)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.authenticate(SASLAuthentication.java:250)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection.loginNonAnonymously(XMPPTCPConnection.java:374)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:456)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection.login(AbstractXMPPConnection.java:431)
    at MyConnector.main(MyConnector.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Apr 13, 2016 11:45:42 AM org.jivesoftware.smack.AbstractXMPPConnection callConnectionClosedOnErrorListener
WARNING: Connection closed with error
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.util.stringencoder.Base64.decode(Base64.java:86)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLMechanism.challengeReceived(SASLMechanism.java:233)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.challengeReceived(SASLAuthentication.java:328)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.SASLAuthentication.challengeReceived(SASLAuthentication.java:313)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.parsePackets(XMPPTCPConnection.java:1051)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader.access$300(XMPPTCPConnection.java:948)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnection$PacketReader$1.run(XMPPTCPConnection.java:963)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am running Openfire 3.9.3 on my Windows laptop and the local IP is 192.168.1.100. The version of the smack library is 4.1.6.

Since it is the login() method that fails, I wonder if there is any Openfire server settings related to login/user that I should be aware of?

In addition, I tried to login with the [Spark IM client](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/spark/) and it could login the local server without problems.

Regards.

---

More info added below.

I just tried an old version (3.4.1) of smack obtained from the [Spark IM github repo](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Spark/tree/master/build/lib/dist) with the following code:

```
    ConnectionConfiguration conf = 
            new ConnectionConfiguration("192.168.1.100", 5222);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(conf);

    connection.connect();
    connection.login("admin", "password");
```

Now the code works fine. Both connect() and login() are OK.

But I really want to know why the lastet version of smack does not work as I expect. Because I am considering using smack on Android while the old version does not support Android natively.

Comment: I`m using last version of Smack and login like you, and its working fine. I have no access to my code now, in 3 hours i`ll try to help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Lets start with step by step*

1) add dependencies

```
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.1.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android-extensions:4.1.0'
compile 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.1.0'
```

2) async task for connect or login to server

```
//connect or login to server
private class MyOpenfireLoginTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Context mContext;
    String username, password;
    ProgressDialog dialog;


    public MyOpenfireLoginTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        username = params[0];
        password = params[1];

        Log.e("Login using ", username + " , " + password);
        Config.config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setUsernameAndPassword(username, password)
                .setHost("your host ex- wec.com")
                .setResource("Android")
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                .setServiceName("domain name(@) ex-   secureserver.net")
                .setPort("5222")
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .build();
        Config.conn1 = new XMPPTCPConnection(Config.config);

        Config.conn1.setPacketReplyTimeout(5000);
        try {
            Config.conn1.connect();
            if (Config.conn1.isConnected()) {
                Log.w("app", "conn done");

            }
            Config.conn1.login();


            if (Config.conn1.isAuthenticated()) {
                Log.w("app", "Auth done");

            } else {
                Log.e("User Not Authenticated", "Needs to Update Password");

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("app", e.toString());
        }

        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        dialog.dismiss();

        if (Config.conn1.isAuthenticated()) {
             //success

        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "username password wrong");

        }
    }
}
```

3)execute above class

```
  if (username.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
        MyOpenfireLoginTask task = new MyOpenfireLoginTask(activity);
        task.execute(username, password);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have do it and works for me. Here is my config

```java
conf.setCompressionEnabled(false)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
```